# Saved options array data randomly disappearing

Tags: wordpress

Not a Wordpress guru. I have inherited a small simple plugin that allows a user to upload an image, which then gets added to an array, and then you can add / edit array values for that image (title, description, etc). The issue I am having is it works great for awhile, then suddenly the form stops saving values to the option_value in the db. This could occur after 10-15 entries. I have verified that the payload being sent to options.php is correct.

Why does this plugin randomly stop saving data to the table?

I have registered the options array

```
$djwp_images = get_option('djwp_images');

add_action('admin_init', 'djwp_register_settings');
function djwp_register_settings() {
   register_setting('djwp_images', 'djwp_images');
   register_setting('djwp_settings', 'djwp_settings');
}
```

A single example shown below of how it iterates through the array for the form.

```
<form class="djform" method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php foreach ($djwp_images as $id => $data) { ?>
    // Single example shows how and array is used to input values
    <input type="hidden" name="djwp_images[<?= $id; ?>][file_url]"
                       value="<?= $file_url ?>"/>
    <? } ?>
    <?= submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

[Full source code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Yfz2JYjk)

Using wordpress: 4.9.8

Comment: Coud it be that the database column field is actually full (length restriction)? So the new value is too large to store in the db? Try to insert/update the new value it should have manually and see if MySQL or phpMyAdmin gives an error.

Comment: The column type was `longtext` which has a size limit of ~4gb. I was not supplying that amount of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to WP. The problem is that on each loop (in `for`) it outputs about 20 inputs. In sum, it outputs hundreds of inputs, and you have to increase the amount of `input_vars` on your server. Either insert this in top of your `functions.php`, it should solve:

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
ini_set('post_max_size', '128M');
```

or update those values in your server's `php.ini` (and restart server)